# Error because of name prefixes with bibentry and Zotero export (noopsort)

Tags: zotero, bibentry, better-bibtex

I've an issue for which I've identified where it comes from but can't find the code to solve it.

I'm managing my bibliography using Zotero automatic export system. In order to have names with prefixes sorted by the main name, Zotero add the following commands in the BibTeX file, as explained [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-bibprefixsort) :

```
...
@ARTICLE{Rayleigh1,
AUTHOR = "{\noopsort{Rayleigh}}{Lord Rayleigh}",
...
}
...
@ARTICLE{deGaulle,
AUTHOR = "{\noopsort{Gaulle}}{de Gaulle}",
...
}
...
@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }
```

In my document, I'm using the following package to manage my bibliographies and citations:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter 
  \renewcommand\BR@b@bibitem[2][]{\BR@bibitem[#1]{#2}\BR@c@bibitem{#2}}        
\makeatother
\nobibliography*
```

In my reference list, my references are rendered as expected, and the sorting is made by the main names. However, when I use *bibentry* to get a full reference in text, I encounter an issue. The names with prefixes are always preceded by the main name.

e.g. gaulledeGaulle, F. second_author, etc...

Do you know how I can enforce bibentry to interpret the \noopsort command correctly? I need to be able to cite correctly full references (not just Author-year citations) in some footnotes, but also to have a specific list of chosen references (divided in sections, therefore cited one by one), in addition to the main one. That's why I need the \bibentry command.

In advance, thank you so much to the ones who can help,

note: I know biber could have been a better choice as backend engine, but it doesn't work with the editor I'm using - Texifier.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend and combine your code to a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Are you sure there are no compilation errors? Since `\noopsort` is defined by a `\providecommand` written to the `.bbl` file through the `@preamble`, either `bibentry` will read the preamble and have the `\noopsort` defined and print the entry correctly OR `bibentry` will not read the `.bbl` file fully and have an undefined `\noopsort`.

Comment: If the guess in my previous comment is correct, you can try placing `\newcommand\noopsort[1]{}` in your preamble next to where you  called `\nobibliography*`.